# How to flush coverage data when my test cause app crash - For ios app

Tags: ios, unit-testing, continuous-integration, code-coverage, gcov

I want to get the code coverage of my tests. So I set the settings, build an app with .gcno files and run it on simulator.

It can get the coverage data successfully if there is no crash issue.

But if the app crashed, I will get nothing.

**So how can I get the code coverage data when the app crash?**

In my thought, this is because it will not call `__gcov_flush()` method when app crash. I only add `app does not run in background` to my plist file, so `__gcov_flush()` is called only at the time I press Home button.

Is there any way to call `__gcov_flush()` before the app crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found way by myself.

Apple provide `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler()` method for app. We can add our own handler before app crash.

So we can call `__gcov_flush()` in this function.

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
extern void __gcov_flush();
// in the exception handler function, call flush like this:
if(__gcov_flush){
    __gcov_flush();
}
```

DONE!